# JavaFX create fxml templates with nodes that text should be replaced

Tags: java, templates, javafx

I have designed a layout with the scenebuilder. The Layout has to show different information in the same way. For example I have a label for username and if I login with my username I want it to be shown so there will be my username. But I have very many of those labels. Is there a way to give the labels a text of (just as an example) %username and in the end just replace it. So that I can create my layouts with scenebuilder and then always put in the content how I need it? I need to load these fxml files multiple times at runtime and nearly always with new information.

Any ideas? I know that I could generate the layout by code and then it would be easy to replace the text but I like the scenebuilder and just wondering whether there is an easy way.

Comment: You're supposed to use bindings, in MVVM or MVC approach. Basically you should at least have model objects and having the UI components' properties and actions bound to them.

Comment: I agree with @AqD. However, you can do a kind of faux "template" by making use of [`FXMLLoader.getNamespace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getNamespace()). The method returns a `Map<String, Object>` which contains mappings of `fx:id` to an `Object` (such as a `Label`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a very basic functionality of Java, JavaFX, and object-oriented programming in general.

There is no need to build multiple FXML documents or fumble with replacing text manually. You can accomplish this with just one FXML document and using a proper MVC (**M**odel-**V**iew-**C**ontroller) approach.

You will want to start with what's known as a Data Model or Model Object. In your case, something like a `User` object:

> **User.java**

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class User {

    // These properties are used to display User data in the Scene
    private StringProperty username = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty emailAddress = new SimpleStringProperty();

    /**
     * A simple constructor to build the User object with a username and email address
     */
    public User(String username, String emailAddress) {

        // Set the values for each of the User properties
        this.username.set(username);
        this.emailAddress.set(emailAddress);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username.get();
    }

    public StringProperty usernameProperty() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username.set(username);
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress.get();
    }

    public StringProperty emailAddressProperty() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress.set(emailAddress);
    }
}
```

The important thing to note in `User.java` is the `StringProperty` declarations. They will come into play when we load our FXML controller.

> **MainLayout.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GridPane hgap="10.0" vgap="5.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="-Infinity" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label text="Username:" />
            <Label text="Email Address:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label fx:id="lblUsername" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Label fx:id="lblEmailAddress" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

This is just a simple FXML layout with a `GridPane` to display our `User` information.

> **MainController.java**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MainController {

    // Here, we define our FXML elements. This allows us to access those elements directly from our Controller
    @FXML
    private Label lblUsername;
    @FXML
    private Label lblEmailAddress;

    // This is the User object that holds the data we want to display
    private User user;

    public MainController(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    /**
     * The initialize() method is called when the FXML document is loaded. This is where we will populate our Scene
     * with the data from the User object passed to the controller's constructor. Since we already created our
     * constructor from the Main class, we have a valid User object to work with
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // There are two basic ways we can setup our Scene to display the User data. This demonstrates the proper Binding
        // method of doing so.

        // Bind the value of each Label to show the corresponding data from the User object
        lblUsername.textProperty().bind(user.usernameProperty());
        lblEmailAddress.textProperty().bind(user.emailAddressProperty());

        // The other method would be to simply set the text for each label. We will comment this out, however, as
        // using the above binding is preferred.
//        lblUsername.setText(user.getUsername());
//        lblEmailAddress.setText(user.getEmailAddress());

    }
}
```

Remember how the `User` object defined two `Property` fields? Now see in our `MainController` that each `Label` also has a `textProperty`?  When we call the `bind()` method on that property, we are basically telling Java to always keep that `textProperty` equal to whatever the `user.username` or `user.emailAddress` properties contain.

> **Main.java**

Now, let's create the class that will create the actual application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // First, let's create a sample User, passing the username and email address to the constructor
        User user = new User("zephyr", "zephyr@home.com");

        primaryStage.setTitle("Data Object Sample");

        try {
            // Tell JavaFX where to find the FXML file and create a loader for it
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainLayout.fxml"));

            // Create a new MainController and pass our sample User to it
            MainController controller = new MainController(user);

            // Now that we've initialized our MainController with a User, let's set the controller for this FXML
            loader.setController(controller);

            // We may now load the FXML document and display the Scene
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));

            // Finally, show the Scene
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

> **That's it!**

As you can see when running the application, your `MainController` sees the `User` and binds the `username` and `emailAddress` properties to the `Label` nodes created in the FXML.

You can now reuse just the one FXML layout to display any `User` you want.

If you want to keep the scene loaded and just change the `User`, you can do so quite easily by adding a "setter" to `MainController.java`:

```
public void setUser (User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

Any time you call that method, the `User` object in `MainController` is changed, JavaFX notices this, and the bindings to each `Label` is updated automatically, displaying the new user's information.

Comment: Thanks, what i didn't know was the way you initiated the controller and got an object back. What I am doing now is just changing the content by methods and without all the binding stuff. I think this can be very useful but a bit to ambitious for my project.